# Converter url de uma string para hyperlink

Tags: php, string, url

Funciona para varios links porem se eu por o mesmo link 2x na string não funciona como fazer?

```
function MontarLink($texto)
{
       if (!is_string ($texto))
           return $texto;

    $er = "/(https:\/\/(www\.|.*?\/)?|http:\/\/(www\.|.*?\/)?|www\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+|_|-)+(\.(([0-9a-zA-Z]|-|_|\/|\?|=|&)+))+/i";

    preg_match_all ($er, $texto, $match);

    foreach ($match[0] as $link)
    {

        //coloca o 'http://' caso o link não o possua
        $link_completo = (stristr($link, "http") === false) ? "http://" . $link : $link;

        $link_len = strlen ($link);

        //troca "&" por "&", tornando o link válido pela W3C
       $web_link = str_replace ("&", "&amp;", $link_completo);
       $texto = str_ireplace ($link, "<a href=\"" . strtolower($web_link) . "\" target=\"_blank\">". (($link_len > 60) ? substr ($web_link, 0, 25). "...". substr ($web_link, -15) : $web_link) ."</a>", $texto);

    }

    return $texto;

}

echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br"); // ESSE FUNCIONA!!!
echo "<br><br>";
echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br outro site www.terra.com.br "); // ESSE FUNCIONA!!!
echo "<br><br>";
echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br mesmo site www.cade.com.br"); // NÃO FUNCIONA!!!
```

Comment: COTD: `//troca "&" por "&", tornando o link válido pela W3C`

Comment: @bfavaretto Poxa... estou falando na mesma string galera... echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br --- segundo site www.cade.com.br terceiro site www.cade.com.br");

Comment: Na verdade parece que está funcionando sim: http://ideone.com/pxSws9

Comment: @bfavaretto cara olha que sinistro!!! achei o erro.. o erro é se for 2 links iguais!!! pus aqui 2 links diferentes e deu certo.. porem com 2 links iguais ele da pau... pq sera?

Comment: fiz umas edições no código para facilitar... veja no final os 3 echo.

Comment: Marque uma das resposta como aceita. Seu problema hoje pode ser o de alguém amanhã e ter uma resposta marcada como aceita ajuda na decisão.

Answer (score 5):

O problema é que quando encontra a primeira ocorrência, você esta substituindo todos, depois vem a segunda ocorrência repetida e você manda substituir denovo, e entra numa reação em cadeia, bagunçando tudo...

Use a função `preg_replace_callback`:

```
function MontarLink($texto)
{
       if (!is_string ($texto))
           return $texto;

    $er = "/(https:\/\/(www\.|.*?\/)?|http:\/\/(www\.|.*?\/)?|www\.)([a-zA-Z0-9]+|_|-)+(\.(([0-9a-zA-Z]|-|_|\/|\?|=|&)+))+/i";

    $texto = preg_replace_callback($er, function($match){
        $link = $match[0];

        //coloca o 'http://' caso o link não o possua
        $link = (stristr($link, "http") === false) ? "http://" . $link : $link;

        //troca "&" por "&", tornando o link válido pela W3C
        $link = str_replace ("&", "&amp;", $link);

        return "<a href=\"" . strtolower($link) . "\" target=\"_blank\">". ((strlen($link) > 60) ? substr ($link, 0, 25). "...". substr ($link, -15) : $link) ."</a>";
    },$texto); 

    return $texto;

}

echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br"); // ESSE FUNCIONA!!!
echo "<br><br>";
echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br outro site www.terra.com.br "); // ESSE FUNCIONA!!!
echo "<br><br>";
echo MontarLink("ola mundo www.cade.com.br mesmo site www.cade.com.br"); // ESSE FUNCIONA!!!
```

Comment: valeu!! agora sim ficou top!!!

Answer (score 3):

Pesquisei um pouco e encontrei [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1960467/753531) no Stack Overflow que além de resolver seu problema de transformação de texto em links ainda leva em consideração várias particularidades de uma URL e ainda cobre links do tipo `mailto`, se é que alguém ainda os usa.

A resposta original tinha alguns equívocos bobos os quais eu consertei e estarei disponibilizando aqui:

```
function makeClickableLinks( $text ) {

    $text = ' ' . html_entity_decode( $text );

    // Full-formed links

    $text = preg_replace(

        '#(((f|ht){1}tps?://)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]+)#i',

        '<a href="\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>',

        $text
    );

    // Links without scheme prefix (i.e. http://)

    $text = preg_replace(

        '#([[:space:]()[{}])(www.[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%_\+.~\#?&//=]+)#i',

        '\\1<a href="http://\\2" target=_blank>\\2</a>',

        $text
    );

    // E-mail links (mailto)

    $text = preg_replace(

        '#([_\.0-9a-z-]+@([0-9a-z][0-9a-z-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,3})#i',

        '<a href="mailto:\\1" target=_blank>\\1</a>',

        $text
    );

    return $text;
}
```

Pode usar da mesma forma que vinha usando:

```
// Link com prefixo http:// e um mailto:

echo makeClickableLinks('

    This is a test clickable link: http://www.websewak.com  You can also try using an email address like test@websewak.com'
), '<br />';

// Links sem o prefixo http://

echo makeClickableLinks( 'www.cade.com.br' ), '<br />';

// Mais de um link no mesmo texto

echo makeClickableLinks(

    'ola mundo www.cade.com.br outro site www.terra.com.br'
), '<br />';

// Dois links iguais

echo makeClickableLinks(

    'ola mundo http://www.cade.com.br mesmo site http://www.cade.com.br'
), '<br />';
```

Comment: Perfeito!! Vlw!!